# Converting this to a std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, this, smart-pointers

I'm facing a small issue in my current codebase. I'm trying to instantiate a new std::shared_ptr of the class ShockRenderSystem. The constructor of ShockRenderSystem takes takes a std::shared_ptr of the class ShockGame, and a sf::VideoMode which isn't relevant in this case. Here's the code I'm trying to do (m_render_system is a std::shared_ptr):

```
m_render_system = std::shared_ptr<ShockRenderSystem>(new ShockRenderSystem((static_cast<std::shared_ptr<ShockGame> >(this)), mode));
```

I'm trying to cast `this` to a std::shared_ptr that I can pass into the constructor. Notice that this code is located in the constructor of ShockGame.

I'm getting the error: `no matching function for call to 'SE::ShockRenderSystem::ShockRenderSystem(std::shared_ptr<SE::ShockGame>*, sf::VideoMode&)' candidate is: SE::ShockRenderSystem::ShockRenderSystem(std::shared_ptr<ShockGame>, sf::VideoMode)`

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: You can't just take any old pointer and cast it to a smart one. That said, I don't see the _syntax_ issue here that the compiler is seeing. You're not passing a `std::shared_ptr<SE::ShockGame>*`.

Comment: Why would you want to construct an object with a shared pointer to itself?!

Comment: I'm not. I'm trying to pass a shared pointer to another class as this. Basically, I'm just trying to cast this (points to ShockGame) to std::shared_ptr<ShockGame> to pass to the constructor ShockRenderSystem.

Answer (score 4):

Derive `ShockGame` from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes to this thread, remember to replace your `this` pointer with `shared_from_this()`.